# How to download code from ubersvn?

Tags: svn, ubersvn

I'm using ubersvn for my project development.Now I need to download the code from the svn to test the code in another machine.How can I download my code from svn,so that '.svn' files should not be present.I'm using rapidsvn client,ubersvn at client.Actually I'm new to the svn,so it might silly question for some one who knows about svn.

Comment: Not sure what ubersvn is, but the normal SVN command for this is named "export" - look whether that is present anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually in ubersvn also we can download the code using "export" option from client side.i,e
is rapid svn which you have mentioned in the your question,you have to give ip address of the 
ubersvn system.

Comment: ok,I've did how you mentioned,but I getting error like "directory already exist".

Comment: OK,check the check box for "overwrite" in the export window and be sure that ip address must be correct and location of the code in the svn must be correct

Comment: Ya,I've tried as you mentioned.Its working fine,thanks very much for your answer and spending your valuable time for us.